# Linux colorize cp

Tags: linux, colors, cp

Simple question, I hope.  I prefer to use the **cp** command aliased to **cp -i** to prevent accidental clobbering of files.  Is there any way to get the "Do you want to overwrite..." message to print is color?  That message is the same color as everything else and, as a partially sighted individual, it'd be helpful if the message was a highlighted color.

Comment: Related: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841143/1258041), [2](http://serverfault.com/q/59262/143702)

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a general way, but you could write a wrapper for cp specifically that would use the ASCII color codes.