# Can cmake emit colorized output during configure step?

Tags: cmake

Sometimes, when running the Cmake configure step, it errors out somewhere and I have to scroll around to find the actual error.

Is it somehow possible to have cmake colorize errors and warnings differently  from diagnostic messages?

**Note:** I am *not* referring to colorized `make` output in the build phase, but output by `cmake` itself.

Comment: CMake outputs errors in stderr, so you can follow one of the approaches in [How to set font color for STDOUT and STDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841143/how-to-set-font-color-for-stdout-and-stderr) to color error output.

Comment: I have thought about that as well (https://github.com/sickill/stderred), although it would be cool to have warnings colored differently from errors. Then again, cmake-gui also doesn't do that, which leads me to believe it's just not intended.

Comment: There is already a feature request at [the CMake GitLab site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19296)